# A Href on a new line

Tags: html, css

i have the following content

```
<div class="venue-description">
   <h4>Description</h4>
                    Nandi Hills are currently undergoing a multi-crore development, including a one crore renovation of the Tipu Fort, via private-public partnership to transform the hills into a tourist hub. The Department of Horticulture is setting up a food court modeled after one in Singapore at a cost of nearly one crore at the hill station.Various varieties of vegetarian and continental food, beverages, bakery products, ice-creams and fresh fruit juices will be available.
<a href="" class="more">view more</a>   
</div>
```

I want to move the `a tag` to a new line. Using `display: block` will create a full width link which is bad for usability.

i do not want to use a `<br/>` tag

Comment: Wrap your text in a paragraph tag as it should be.

Comment: Put a `<br />` before the link.

Comment: _i do not want to use a <br/> tag_ why, though?

Comment: bcos that content is coming dynamically from a Text editor.

Comment: The text under your `h4` tag should probably be wrapped in a `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/28tbM/)

```
a::before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just put

```
<br/>
```

after

```
<h4>Description</h4>
                    Nandi Hills are currently undergoing a multi-crore development, including a one crore renovation of the Tipu Fort, via private-public partnership to transform the hills into a tourist hub. The Department of Horticulture is setting up a food court modeled after one in Singapore at a cost of nearly one crore at the hill station.Various varieties of vegetarian and continental food, beverages, bakery products, ice-creams and fresh fruit juices will be available.
```

Comment: A <br/> element in that place would be non-sementical. We should do our best to keep the html clean and semantical, and work the layout only from CSS.